# How to merge SEOmatic object in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, plugin-seomatic, merge

I'm using SEOmatic plugin in craft cms 3 and I need to set the seoTitle in my template but can't figure out how to do it...

I know that in Craft 2, it was possible to merge the seomatic variable. I tried something like this :

```
{% set seomatic = seomatic|merge({
    meta: {
        seoTitle: 'my title'
    }
}) %}
```

But it doesn't work because the merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", and I got object... I'm kind of stuck with this issue.

Has anyone ever managed to make a merge of seoTitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [SEOmatic docs](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#seomatic-variables), something like this should do the trick nicely:

```
{% do seomatic.meta.seoTitle("my title") %}
```

Comment: Okay I feel really dumb to have missed this part of the doc... It worked thank you very much !

Comment: No worries! To be completely honest, Andrew's plugin docs are a bit hard to go through since they're just one long README. Personally, I would love to see the docs migrated to his website where they could be organized a little better (using Vuepress or something similar). Would be easier to find and navigate to the section you want to read about...

Comment: I agree. And that's exactly what I plan to do @JalenDavenport

Comment: Lol - I wondered if you would see this  Thanks! 